# Create Single Pixel Rectangle

Tags: android

I want to create a single pixel stroke rectangle, but android is rendering two pixels.

Here is my xml code:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">    
        <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Here is the top left corner of what is rendered:

[image]

My only guess is that this background is not lining up with the device pixels.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? can you accept an answer or add the right answer to close this question and get it off the unanswered list, thanks!

Comment: This has not been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the bi-linear filtration introduced in honeycomb and later.  There are two solutions:

1. Disable all hardware acceleration in the manifest (bad idea) with this tag

   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
2. Use the xml attribute on affected views to render with software only

   android:layerType="software"

I found the solution here:

[Blurred 1dip shape lines (borders) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641772/blurred-1dip-shape-linesborders-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially a line? You could try using something like

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

EDIT: whoops, think I misunderstood. You could always just draw a rectangle using lines though I guess.

Comment: Try using dp instead, as Nick said.

Answer (score 0):

px has different meanings on different screen sizes. I'm guessing this is on a bigger screen? Try changing the unit to dp and the anti-aliasing affect should disappear

*edit*: actually this wont solve your issue if you just want the physical thickness of the line on your screen to be half its current size. It *will* make it look equivalent on all types of screen though and keep a solid appearance, if that's your complaint

Comment: Using dp does not work.  Which makes sense because according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension, dp could change in pixel height based on screen density.  I want pixel since I want exactly 1 pixel, regardless of screen density.

Comment: Yes although that means on bigger screens the pixel would probably not even be noticable, that's why dp are better. If you are correct about the effect being caused by things not lining up, then this approach would solve it. Otherwise the only other option I can see is a well designed 9 patch