# Blurred 1dip shape lines (borders) on Android

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

Here is the screenshot from my app:

[image]

It's taken from `Samsung Galaxy Note` 10.1 (`mdpi` 149 `ppi`).

My client thinks that the border line around bottom buttons and rounded rectangle above are blurred.

I'm using shape as a background which looks like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp" />

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/dark_gray" />

    <solid android:color="@color/sepia_bright" />

</shape>
```

When I use simple view as a line with 1dp height like this:

```
<View
    android:background="@color/bright_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

It's perfectly sharp as you can see on next screenshot:

[image]

Simple  horizontal lines are ok, but rectangle around graph is blurred again.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess would be that this is a problem with bi-linear filtration (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering).

To fix it, see The [View#setLayerType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29%20%22View#setLayerType) method.

I had an issue with this in a custom view. Inside my view's init method, I have the following code:

```
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);          
    }
```

This fixed my issue, but you could do the same thing using the `android:layerType` xml attribute, or the `setLayerType` method in code on your view.

Comment: Yes, thanks! This totally solved problem with lines. It looks like more brutal way to solve this is to se android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in <application> in AndroidManifest.xml
But I still have a problem with rounded corners, they still look very bad, but I don't know if it could be better.